# docker file pip install locally

Tags: python, docker, image, pip, internet-explorer-11

this is my docker file:

```
WORKDIR /scan

RUN pip install pymongo
RUN pip install netmiko
RUN pip install pyats[full]
ENV Testbed=
ENV arr=
# ENV device=
# ENV id=

COPY . /scan
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I want to pip install this particular packages locally Like from a tar files. I want to build the image without any internet, so that's why I need it to be locally so that the pip will take them from local and not from internet.
I just want to clarify that when I pip install requirements it will go anyway to the internet, I already try it.

Comment: i did this earlier, bit of setup required. is there any way you can run the build in a internet pc and then move the built image to a pc with no internet?

Comment: yes i can do that. but u think there isn't any way to build from 0 without any internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need base image in dockerfiles:

```
# Set the base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /scan

# Copy the local tar files into the image
COPY your_package1.tar.gz your_package2.tar.gz /tmp/

# Install packages from local tar files
RUN pip install /tmp/your_package1.tar.gz && \
    pip install /tmp/your_package2.tar.gz

# Set environment variables if needed
ENV Testbed=
ENV arr=

# Copy the rest of your application files
COPY . /scan

# Specify the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
```

For running any commands in the process of building docker image (keyword **RUN**):

```
# Install system packages using apt-get
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-server apache2 supervisor
```

Comment: thanks, i want to also to this:`apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server apache2 supervisor` i need to download them too?

Comment: If this image will have apt-get it will work - but maybe it hasn't.

Comment: yes this requires internet, there is a way to install it locally?

Answer (score 2):

Build you docker images from a internet PC:

```
docker build –t myimage:0.1 .
```

Save the built image:

```
docker save -o <path for generated tar file> <image name>
```

In you case:

```
docker save -o c:/myimage_0-1.tar myimage:0.1
```

Then copy your image to a new system (which has no internet access) with regular file transfer tools such as `cp`, `scp`, or `rsync` (preferred for big files). After that you will have to load the image into Docker:

```
docker load -i <path to image tar file>
```

Then you can use the `run` command to start the image.